# Wget output document and headers to STDOUT

Tags: http, wget

I'm trying to output the document body and its headers to STDOUT by doing

```
wget -S -O - http://google.com
```

...but it shows only the HTML document.

**Update:** Got it to work with

```
wget --save-headers --output-document - http://google.com
```

`wget --version` shows my version is `GNU Wget 1.11.4 Red Hat modified`.

Comment: I just tried this worked great but `--save-headers` was actually `-save-headers`

Comment: and `wget -qS <url>` for just [tag:http] **headers** (eq. to `curl -IL`)

Comment: wget -qS expect interactive response

Answer (score 207):

Try the following

```
wget -q -S -O - www.google.com 2>&1
```

Note the trailing `-`. This is part of the normal command argument for `-O` to cat out to a file, but since we don't use `>` to direct to a file, it goes out to the shell. You can use `-qO-` or `-qO -`.

Comment: the `-S` option wasn't supported on my `alpine` linux container. I omitted it and all was good

Comment: According to the GNU man page “If - is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion.” It is more clearly written with a preceding whitespace.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense. OP asked to show headers, not hide them

Answer (score 58):

`wget -S -O - http://google.com` works as expected for me, *but* with a caveat: the headers are considered debugging information and as such they are sent to the *standard error* rather than the standard output. If you are redirecting the standard output to a file or another process, you will only get the document contents.

You can try redirecting the standard error to the standard output as a possible solution. For example, in `bash`:

```
$ wget -q -S -O - 2>&1 | grep ...
```

or

```
$ wget -q -S -O - 1>wget.txt 2>&1
```

The `-q` option suppresses the progress bar and some other annoyingly chatty parts of the `wget` output.

Comment: the `-S` option wasn't supported on my `alpine` linux container. I omitted it and all was good

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno You can install a proper wget with `apk add wget`, otherwise only a busybox version is used.

Answer (score 28):

It works here:

```
    $ wget -S -O - http://google.com
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Location: http://www.google.com/
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Date: Sat, 25 Aug 2012 10:15:38 GMT
  Expires: Mon, 24 Sep 2012 10:15:38 GMT
  Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
  Server: gws
  Content-Length: 219
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
--2012-08-25 12:20:29--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 173.194.69.99, 173.194.69.104, 173.194.69.106, ...

  ...skipped a few more redirections ...

    [<=>                                                                                                                                     ] 0           --.-K/s              
<!doctype html><html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><head><meta itemprop="image" content="/images/google_favicon_128.png"><ti 

... skipped ...
```

perhaps you need to update your wget (`~$ wget --version
GNU Wget 1.14 built on linux-gnu.`)

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me for printing response with header:

```
wget --server-response http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: You might want to add `--spider` arg. This useful cause don't download any page content.

Answer (score 7):

This will not work:

```
wget -q -S -O - google.com 1>wget.txt 2>&1
```

since redirects are evaluated right to left, this sends html to wget.txt and the header to STDOUT:

```
wget -q -S -O - google.com 2>&1 1>wget.txt
```