# How to make a request to a url from a remote linux server?

Tags: linux, rest, putty

I need to see the response from a get request of a REST url on a remote linux server. The only access I have to the remote linux server is through putty. Is there a way to go through with it?

I think my question may not be very clear. Let me rephrase.

I need to access the REST url exposed from an ip different from that of this linux server from this linux server that I am connected through putty.
My application runs on this linux server. I am unable to make the REST call using my application (getting EOF exception at webresource.get(ClientResponse.class) method. Since, I dont have access to a browser on the linux server, is there a way to still be able to see if we can get a (JSON) response by making a get request to that REST url from putty using a putty command?

Comment: you can make a tcp request using netcat you just need to put the http in yourself. If you need ssl/tls I believe there is an openssl tool for that.

Comment: If that remote server offers a REST API, then why can't you simply make a http request to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl is a tool that you can send HTTP requests 
`curl -X GET $URL`

Answer (score 0):

My answer helps if you have ssh access to your linux server.
Linux offers several packages.
The most simple and common one is called wget.
For example if your url is `www.google.com`, you can execute this command.

```
wget -qO- www.google.com
```

Another powerful tool is `curl`, however you need to install it on your linux. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-curl-command-on-a-ubuntu-linux/

It gives you a lot of options such as setting the header of request which might be used for RestAPI authentication.
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

A simple example is

```
curl www.google.com
```

Hope that helps.

Source: [Wget output document and headers to STDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120935/wget-output-document-and-headers-to-stdout)